# Is it safe to eat these lightly spotted mint leaves?

Tags: leaves, mint

Note: I'm not a gardener.

[image: Top side of leaf]

[image: Bottom side of same leaf]

[image: Another leaf]

[image: second leaf from the bottom side]

These mint plants were planted by my family a while back in the garden.

I don't know why these white/yellowish spots appear on the leaves, but I'll try to give detail of the environment as best as I can.

1. This is in Cairo, Egypt, in the summer. Heat rises up to 35-40 degrees celsius in the morning these days.
2. The people who run our compound spray pesticides on plants in gardens, and a larger white cloudy/smoky looking pesticide around the entire compound for mosquitoes
3. I have no idea what the soil conditions are, or any way to find out.

If it's **not** safe to eat these leaves due to their spots, is it okay to eat leaves which don't have those spots but are from the same plant?

Comment: Reminder: comments are not for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These dots must be from whitefly: it looks like the insect sits on a leaf underside.
Eating leaves slightly chewed by insects is completely OK, just wash them.

**It is the insecticide you should worry about.** Check what substance they use and what is the waiting period before eating is allowed.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will try to check.